# Check if two tables exist in database

Tags: c#, ms-access, if-statement

I have database pavadinimas.mdf, which contains two tables: Vehicle and Repairs. I want to check if both tables exist in database. So, far I managed to check if one table exist, but how to check if both exist, if not create them.

Here is my code:

```
string tblnm = "Vehicle";
            SqlConnection conn;
            using (conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                conn.Open();           
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = @"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                       WHERE TABLE_NAME='" + tblnm + "') SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0"; ;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                int x = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                conn.Close();
                if (x == 2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Lentelės yra");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Lenteliu nėra.Sukuriama");
                }
```

I also have code which should create table. Here is code:

```
string table1 = "Repairs";
                 SqlConnection conn;
                 conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
                     conn.Open();
                     string createString = "CREATE TABLE [dbo].['" + table1 + "'](" + "[VIN] [nvarchar](50)," + "[Taisymas] [nvarchar](50)," + "[Kaina] [decimal](18, 2))";
                       SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(createString, conn);
                       sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                       conn.Close();
```

But this code don't create table in my database. Then I call this method, it is saying that table already exist, but when I check tables in database it's nothing, empty...

Comment: If one table doesn't exist, wouldn't you want to create it?

Comment: just do what you are doing, for both of them

Comment: Yeah, but for now I want to check, I have another method for creating tables.

Comment: I posted something I think should work, but I do see a potential bug in your code.  You have `ExecuteNonQuery` followed by `ExecuteScalar`.  Don't you typically have one or the other?  I think the first one is invalidating the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a parameter and looping through the tables?

```
conn.Open();
var cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(
    @"SELECT count (*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME",
    conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TABLE_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar);

List<String> tables = new List<string>() { "Vehicles", "Repairs" };

foreach (string tableName in tables)
{
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = tableName;
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

    if (x == 0)
        CreateTable(tableName, conn);
}
conn.Close();
```

-- EDIT --

`CreateTable` method was added above, and the code would look something like this.  Caveat -- this is EXTREMELY brute force, but in the absence of other information, is is one way to accomplish the task, as I best understand your issue.

```
private void CreateTable(String TableName, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn)
{
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(@"create table [");
    sql.Append(TableName);
    sql.AppendLine(@"] (");

    switch (TableName)
    {
        case "Vehicle":
            sql.AppendLine("[VIN] varchar(100),");
            sql.AppendLine("[Manufacturer] varchar(100),");
            sql.AppendLine("[Model] varchar(100),");
            sql.AppendLine("[Year] integer");
            break;
        case "Repair":
            sql.AppendLine("[VIN] varchar(100),");
            sql.AppendLine("[Correction] varchar(100),");
            sql.AppendLine("[Price] decimal");
            break;
    }

    sql.Append(")");

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(
        sql.ToString, conn);

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Created Table " + TableName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Oops, I did it again");
    }
}
```

Comment: I still need, code which checks if both tables exist do nothing. If one exist or both don't exist call method to create them.

Comment: Okay, now I understand.  In that case, what is the structure of each table, or are you saying if one exists, make it look like the other?

Comment: Table Vehicle have columns, VIN, manucfacturer, model, year. Table Repairs have columns VIN, correction, price.

Comment: Not that this approach is ideal, but see if it gets you in the direction you seek...

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something similar to:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='tbl1') AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='tbl2') SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0
```

Comment: Wrote like this: `cmd.CommandText = @"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='" + tblnm + "') AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='" + tblnm1 + "') SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0"; ; `Still not working..

Comment: @SiRaZz That query will do the trick for you. Just check that you dont include the schema name into the table name (tblnm & tblnm1). But the biggest problem with your code is your check "if (x == 2)". That query will return 1 or 0 only, so it should be x == 1

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a `for` loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  if (i = 0)
  {
    string tblnm = "Vehicle";
  }
  else
  {
    string tblnm = "Repairs";
  }

        SqlConnection conn;
        using (conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            conn.Open();           
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                   WHERE TABLE_NAME='" + tblnm + "') SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0"; ;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            conn.Close();
            if (x == 2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Lentelės yra");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Lenteliu nėra.Sukuriama");
            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for answer, but your code not working, it still give me that tables not exist..

Comment: I don't know what language you're using so I can't tell exactly what the messageboxes should say, but I can tell you x will never equal 2.  It's either gonna be 1 or 0.

Comment: "x will never equal 2"  `+1`

Comment: When it does i++ it goes out of range and is thus ignored.